# booting to py script and then ending

Tags: python, kill, boot

I've used this ["instructable" method](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/) to run my script on boot which works fine, but I have no way to end the program while the Pi is running. I but to the GUI in Raspbian.

I tried the pygame module as described but nothing happens.

I think a shell should appear in which I can see the executed program and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to end if desired.

i have no end condition. perhaps someone may suggest a method?
the script is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as IO
import time
import random

IO.setwarnings(False)
IO.setmode(IO.BCM)
IO.setup(26, IO.OUT)
IO.setup(16, IO.OUT)
IO.setup(13, IO.OUT)
IO.setup(27, IO.OUT)
IO.setup(18, IO.OUT)
IO.setup(17, IO.OUT)
IO.setup(4, IO.IN)

def pattern1():
    (IO.output(26, True), IO.output(16, True), IO.output(27, True), IO.output(18, True), IO.output(13, False), IO.output(17, False), time.sleep(0.75), IO.output(16, True), IO.output(13, True), IO.output(18, True), IO.output(17, True), IO.output(26, False), IO.output(27, False), time.sleep(0.75), IO.output(13, True), IO.output(27, True), IO.output(17, True), IO.output(26, True), IO.output(16, False), IO.output(18, False), time.sleep(0.75))
def pattern2():
    (IO.output(26, True), IO.output(16, True), IO.output(27, True), IO.output(18, True), IO.output(13, True), IO.output(17, True), time.sleep(0.5))
def pattern_off():
    (IO.output(26, False), IO.output(16, False), IO.output(13, False), IO.output(27, False), IO.output(18, False), IO.output(17, False))
def pattern_flasher_x_3():
    (pattern_off(), time.sleep(0.5), pattern2(), time.sleep(0.5), pattern_off(), time.sleep(0.5), pattern2(), time.sleep(0.5), pattern_off(), time.sleep(0.5), pattern2(), time.sleep(0.5))

try:
    while True:
        if IO.input(4)==1:
            for i in range(50):
                pattern1()
            for i in range(1):
                pattern_flasher_x_3()
            else:
                pattern_off()
    while False:
        pattern_off()


finally:
    IO.cleanup()
```

Comment: How are you booting the Pi? Is it loading Raspian with gui, starting at the terminal or running 'headless' so you access it over ssh?

Comment: What is your script? What are the stop conditions? You need to tell us more about it.

Comment: there is no stop condition. before using the launcher.sh to run after boot i'd just cntrl+c to end it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did some looking around and found that having an auxiliary input to trigger a "quit" works.
in the while True and while False parts i added:

```
if IO.input(25) == True:
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've had scripts run on boot on Linux and wanted to stop them, the answer was to use the command `top` in the terminal to find the process and then `sudo kill [processnumber]` to stop it. The snag is finding your process. It will most likely be named Python. As with any command involving sudo be very careful - killing random processes is not recommended ;-) .

I'd also recommend install htop as the interface is a little prettier.

Adding a quit trigger seems like a much better solution if you can manage it